# Using DataContext cache to preload child collection

Tags: linq-to-sql

In an attempt to reduce round-trips to the database, I was hoping to 'preload' child collections for a parent object.  My hope was that if I loaded the objects that make up the child collection into the DataContext cache, Linq2SQL would use those objects instead of going to the database.

For example, assume I have a Person objects with two child collections: Children and Cars.

I thought this might work:

```
var children = from p in dbc.Person
               select p.Children;

var cars = from p in dbc.Person
           select p.Cars;

var people = from p in dbc.Person
             select p;


var dummy1 = children.ToList();
var dummy2 = cars.ToList();

foreach(var person in people){
    Debug.WriteLine(person.Children.Count);
}
```

But instead, I'm still getting one trip to the database for every call to `person.Children.Count`, even though all the children are already loaded in the DataContext.

Ultimately, what I'm looking for is a way to load a full object graph (with multiple child collections) in as few trips to the database as possible.

I'm aware of the `DataLoadOptions` class (and `LoadWith`), but it's limited to one child collection, and that's a problem for me.

I wouldn't mind using a stored procedure if I was still able to build up the full object graph (and still have a Linq2SQL object, of course) without a lot of extra manipulation of the objects.

Comment: Have you considered `Include` and disabling the proxy creation / lazy loading?

Comment: I haven't found any reference to 'Include' in L2S...isn't than an EF feature? I see DamienG (one of Microsoft's L2S and EF devs) posted this article (http://damieng.com/blog/2010/05/21/include-for-linq-to-sql-and-maybe-other-providers) but that doesn't work with one-to-many relationships.

Comment: I assumed from your use of `DataContext` that you were using entity framework. What type of ORM are you using? What type of connector are you using? Can you make this question a little more defined?

Comment: @TravisJ: He mentions that he is using Linq-to-SQL in the first paragraph of the question. @Nathan: Why do you assume that `LoadWith` is limited to one child collection? You could simply use multiple `LoadWith` calls to load multiple child collections. Don't forget to set `DeferredLoadingEnabled` to false.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you require is directly possible with LINQ-SQL or even SQL in the way that your expecting.

When you consider how SQL works, a single one-many relationship can easily be flattened by an inner/left join. After this, if you want another set of objects including, you could theoretically write another left join which would bring back all the rows in the other table. But imagine the output SQL would provide, it's not easily workable back into an object graph. ORM's will typically start to query per row to provide this data. An example of this is to write multiple level `DataLoadOptions` using LINQ-SQL, you will start to see this.

Also, the impact on performance with many LEFT JOINs will easily outweigh the perceived benefits of single querying.

Consider your example. You are fetching *ALL* of the rows back from these two tables. This poses two problems further down the line:

- The tables may get much more data in them than you expect. Pulling back 1000's of rows in SQL all at once may not be good for performance. You then expect LINQ-SQL to search the lists for matching objects. Dependent on use, I imagine SQL can provide this data faster.
- The behavior you expect is hidden, and to me would be unusual that running a SELECT on a large table could potentially bloat the memory usage of the app by caching all of the rows. Maybe they could include it as an option or provide your own extension methods.

**Solution**

I would personally start to look at caching the data outside of LINQ-SQL, and then retrieve objects from the ASP.Net / Memory Cache / Your Cache provider, if it is deemed that the full object graph is expensive to create.

One level of `DataLoadOptions` plus relying on the built-in entity relationships + some manual caching will probably save many a headache.

I have come across this particular problem a few times and haven't thought of anything else yet.